# How to use $regex inside $or as an Aggregation Expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query which allows the user to filter by some string field using a format that looks like: *"Where description of the latest inspection is any of: `foo` or `bar`"*. This works great with the following query:

```
db.getCollection('permits').find({
  '$expr': {
    '$let': {
      vars: {
        latestInspection: {
          '$arrayElemAt': ['$inspections', {
            '$indexOfArray': ['$inspections.inspectionDate', {
              '$max': '$inspections.inspectionDate'
            }]
          }]
        }
      },
      in: {
        '$in': ['$$latestInspection.description', ['Fire inspection on property', 'Health inspection']]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What I want is for the user to be able to use wildcards which I turn into regular expressions: *"Where description of the latest inspection is any of: `Health inspection` or `Found a * at the property`"*.

The regex I get, don't need help with that. The problem I'm facing is, apparently [the aggregation `$in` operator does not support matching by regular expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/). So I thought I'd build this using `$or` since the docs **don't** say I can't use regex. This was my best attempt:

```
db.getCollection('permits').find({
  '$expr': {
    '$let': {
      vars: {
        latestInspection: {
          '$arrayElemAt': ['$inspections', {
            '$indexOfArray': ['$inspections.inspectionDate', {
              '$max': '$inspections.inspectionDate'
            }]
          }]
        }
      },
      in: {
        '$or': [{
          '$$latestInspection.description': {
            '$regex': /^Found a .* at the property$/
          }
        }, {
          '$$latestInspection.description': 'Health inspection'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Except I'm getting the error:

```
"Unrecognized expression '$$latestInspection.description'"
```

I'm thinking I can't use `$$latestInspection.description` as an object key but I'm not sure (my knowledge here is limited) and I can't figure out another way to do what I want. So you see I wasn't even able to get far enough to see if I can use `$regex` in `$or`. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) is an aggregation expression, and the documentation may not *"say you cannot explicitly"*, but the [lack of any named operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and the [JIRA issue SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) certainly say that. So if you need a regular expression then you really have no other option than using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) instead:

```
db.getCollection('permits').find({
  "$where": function() {
    var description = this.inspections
       .sort((a,b) => b.inspectionDate.valueOf() - a.inspectionDate.valueOf())
       .shift().description;

     return /^Found a .* at the property$/.test(description) ||
           description === "Health Inspection";

  }
})
```

You can still use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and aggregation expressions for an exact match, or just keep the comparison within the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) anyway. But at this time the only regular expressions MongoDB understands is [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) within a ["query" expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/).

If you did actually *"require"* an aggregation pipeline expression that precludes you from using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), then the only current valid approach is to first "project" the field separately from the array and then [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with the regular query expression:

```
db.getCollection('permits').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "lastDescription": {
       "$arrayElemAt": [
         "$inspections.description",
         { "$indexOfArray": [
           "$inspections.inspectionDate",
           { "$max": "$inspections.inspectionDate" }
         ]}
       ]
     }
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "lastDescription": {
      "$in": [/^Found a .* at the property$/,/Health Inspection/]
    }
  }}
])
```

Which leads us to the fact that you appear to be looking for the item in the array with the maximum date value. The JavaScript syntax should be making it clear that the correct approach here is instead to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) the array on "update". In that way the "first" item in the array can be the "latest". And this is something you can do with a regular query.

To maintain the order, ensure new items are added to the array with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) like this:

```
db.getCollection('permits').updateOne(
  { "_id": _idOfDocument },
  {
    "$push": {
      "inspections": {
        "$each": [{ /* Detail of inspection object */ }],
        "$sort": { "inspectionDate": -1 }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

In fact with an empty array argument to [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) an [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) will update all your existing documents:

```
db.getCollection('permits').updateMany(
  { },
  {
    "$push": {
      "inspections": {
        "$each": [],
        "$sort": { "inspectionDate": -1 }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

These really only should be necessary when you in fact "alter" the date stored during updates, and those updates are best issued with [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to effectively do "both" the update and the "sort" of the array:

```
db.getCollection('permits').bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": _idOfDocument, "inspections._id": indentifierForArrayElement },
    "update": {
      "$set": { "inspections.$.inspectionDate": new Date() }
    }
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": _idOfDocument },
    "update": {
      "$push": { "inspections": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "inspectionDate": -1 } } }
    }
  }}
])
```

However if you did not ever actually "alter" the date, then it probably makes more sense to simply use the [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier and "pre-pend" to the array instead of "appending", and avoiding any overhead of a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/):

```
db.getCollection('permits').updateOne(
  { "_id": _idOfDocument },
  { 
    "$push": { 
      "inspections": {
        "$each": [{ /* Detail of inspection object */ }],
        "$position": 0
      }
    }
  }
)
```

With the array permanently sorted or at least constructed so the "latest" date is actually always the "first" entry, then you can simply use a regular query expression:

```
db.getCollection('permits').find({
  "inspections.0.description": { 
    "$in": [/^Found a .* at the property$/,/Health Inspection/]
  }
})
```

So the lesson here is don't try and force calculated expressions upon your logic where you really don't need to. There should be no compelling reason why you cannot order the array content as "stored" to have the *"latest date **first**"*, and even if you thought you needed the array in any other order then you probably should weigh up which usage case is more important.

Once reodered you can even take advantage of an index to some extent as long as the regular expressions are either anchored to the beginning of string or at least something else in the query expression does an exact match.

In the event you feel you really cannot reorder the array, then the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) query is your only present option until the JIRA issue resolves. Which is hopefully actually for the 4.1 release as currently targeted, but that is more than likely 6 months to a year at best estimate.

Comment: Thorough explanation. And I appreciate all the other options. I've been thinking about storing those subdocuments by inspectionDate, it hadn't occurred to me to store them in "reverse order" which makes for the cleanest query by far.

Comment: @Joao It is pretty much the recommended pattern. For completeness I also added that you can do a "separate" `$match` stage within an aggregation pipeline, and also where you would always expect the "latest" entry to the be last thing added to the array you can always "pre-pend" using `$position`.