# MongoDB query for showing results with logs before

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have MongoDB collection that stores posts. For each post, I collect user interactions with this post (ex. click, full read, display).
I am not sure what is the proper way to query collection for finding posts that **have not been displayed to given user for last week**.
Right now the structure looks like:

```
id: ...
createdAt: ...
text: ...
...
interactions:
    reads: []
    clicks: []
    displays: [
      0: {
        user: ObjectId,
        date: 2018-06-13 01:00:00
      },
      1: {
        user: ObjectId,
        date: 2018-06-12 01:00:00
      },
    ]
```

I am wondering is it possible to filter by `lastDisplay < given date` as a part of `find()` query.
Other solutions that come to my mind are:

- to use map-reduce (but I'm not sure how should it be placed here),
- create an additional field, that could store `lastDisplay` for each company, but I'm not sure is so much redundancy really needed

What should be preferred solution to get data with that kind of filtering?

Comment: Or you can just store the "last" array member as the very first one by pre-pending on each addition or via the `$sort` modifier to `$push`. MapReduce and Aggregate are "hacks" where the "optimal" solution is to actually store the array in the order you need it. You cannot query the "last" element of the array, but you can do the "first" with a very simple query.

Comment: See [How to use $regex inside $or as an Aggregation Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633662/2313887) for examples of what I mean about changing the stored array order so the "last" is actually "first"